# Can I change "was" to "had been", when expressing age?

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech, backshifting

Actually, I teach English language for 12 years, but today I got confused when I tried to report this sentence:

> William: 'I lived in China until I was fifteen.'
> William said that he had lived in China until he was fifteen.

The problem is that if we want to report a sentence, we have to change the verb tense. For example, the past simple will be changed to the past perfect simple. I see the example above doesn't follow the rule. I mean if we change the tense from the past simple tense to the past perfect tense, the sentence will be:

> William said that he had lived in China until he had been fifteen.

So can you please explain that to me?

Comment: *The problem is that if we want to report a sentence, we have to change the verb tense.* -- The real problem that this is not true. It is **general guidance**; it is not a rule. A common exception to the rule is known a "the eternal truth". -- A: "The world is not flat." -- B: "What did you say?" -- A: "I said that The world is not flat." The fact that William left China when he was 15 years old is true no matter when it is said.

Comment: Your first attempt was good. Go with that.

Comment: I have taught OR have been teaching English for 5 years., A present simple can **never ever** be used with time periods, unless you are using the very fancy historical present.

Comment: *He said he [**had**] left school at age 15*. [Both versions are fine,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said+he+left+school%2Csaid+he+had+left+school&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaid%20he%20left%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaid%20he%20had%20left%20school%3B%2Cc0) (and can mean exactly the same).

Comment: My answer is supported and I copied faithfully the quotations, which includes the use of curly quotes (my personal preference) and single quotes used by the authors in their authoritative books. If you disagree with the answer that's fine. I enjoyed doing the research and hope it will help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

When constructing indirect speech, changing the *simple past* or the *past progressive* to the *past perfect* or the *past perfect progressive* is not always necessary.

1.a “I **was** hungry” said Joe. (direct speech)
1.b Joe said he **was** hungry. (Indirect speech)

2.a “I got married when I **was** just 17” she said.
2.b She told me that she **was** 17 when she got married.

3.a Journalist: “When did you and Mel meet for the first time?”
Rory: “We **were** both **studying** in Oxford when we MET.”
3.b He told the journalist they HAD MET when they **were studying** in Oxford.
3.c He told the journalist they MET when they **were studying** in Oxford.

Most of the verbs in the direct speech examples are in the simple past, these do not need to change tense in indirect speech (also known as ‘reported speech’) because the actions they refer to happened in the *past*. An  exception can be seen in 3.b where the meeting and the studying both occurred in the past but the meeting happened *before* the two people had completed their studies. However, changing the tenses is still not obligatory as shown in 3c. The sentence is natural for the situation being described.

Under Chapter 31, **Indirect Speech**, the authors of APEG <sup>1</sup> explain [emphasis in **bold** mine]:

> #### 309 Past Tenses sometimes remain unchanged
>
> **C** In written English past tenses usually do change to past perfect but there are the following exceptions:
>
> 1. Past/Past continuous tenses in time clauses do not normally change:
>
> - He said, ‘When we **were living/lived** in Paris…’= *He said that when they **were living/lived** in Paris*…
>
> The main verb of such sentences can either remain unchanged or become the past perfect:
>
> - *He said,* ‘*When we **were living/lived** in Paris we often **saw** Paul.*’=
> - *He said that when they **were living/lived** in Paris they often **saw** /had often seen Paul.*
>
> 2. A past tense used to describe a state of affairs which still exists when the speech is reported **remains unchanged**.
>
> - *She said, ‘I decided not to buy the house because **it was** on a main road’* = *She said that she had decided not to buy the house
>   because **it was** on a main road.*

In AGIU <sup>2</sup> the author confirms that if the situation being described happened in the past and has not changed, the past simple can be used instead of the past perfect.

> ### 45 Verb tense in that-clauses
>
> (D)
>
> - ‘I learnt how to eat with chopsticks when I **was** in Hong Kong’ ➞ Mary said that she **had learnt/learnt** how to eat with chopsticks when she **was** in Hong Kong.
> - ‘I posted the card yesterday.’ ➞ She reassured me that she **had posted/posted** the card.

The same piece of advice is provided by the author of EGIU <sup>3</sup> 4th Ed. in unit 47, section C and by Michael Swan, the author of PEG <sup>4</sup>, who says under the entry of *reported speech*

> It is important to realise that the tenses in reported speech are not
> ‘special’. They are (almost always) just the normal tenses for the
> situation we are talking about. Compare:
>
> - She **was** tired so she went home
> - She said she **was** tired and she went home.

The first sentence describes the event using the simple past tense, the second sentence uses the same tense in reported speech because we are still talking about the past.

Martin Parrott, the author of GFELT <sup>5</sup>, in chapter 18 writes:

> ### Choosing between past simple and past perfect
>
> Sometimes, a sequence of events may be so clear in the context that we
> don't need to make this additionally clear in the tenses we choose.
> For example, the following is from a report of the victim of a mugging
> describing how he was attacked. The past simple is used for both the
> reporting verb said and for the much earlier events *was hit* and *were tied* (*had been hit*… and *had been tied*… are possible but
> unnecessary alternatives).
>
> > > *He said he was hit over the head with a hefty object and struck fairly smartly between the legs, while his hands were tied behind his back with telephone wire.*

### Conclusion

It is an oversimplification that the tenses must *always* change when converting direct speech into reported speech. These tips are often found in student school books, which serve to guide learners and students alike but often lead to dogmatic rules “*The problem is that if we want to report a sentence, we have to change the verb tense.*”  This “rule” is unsupported by the majority of the most renowned authors of English grammar books.

**References**

1. *A Practical English Grammar* 4th Ed (1985). By A.J.Thomson and A.V.Martinet
2. *Advanced Grammar in Use* (199) By Martin Hewings
3. *English Grammar in Use* (2012) By Raymond Murphy
4. *Practical English Usage* (1980) By Michael swan
5. *Grammar for English Language Teachers* (2010) By Martin Parrott

Comment: This does not address the core issue, the unacceptability of the 'until he had been fifteen' string (whether in reported speech or not).

Comment: 'The core problem for the OP is that "For example, the past simple will be changed to the past perfect simple" Which I addressed clearly in my answer.' ... And others have clearly addressed in previous ones. The issue which remains an ELU topic (unless I've missed duplicates here) is the acceptability of 'until he had been fifteen' _anywhere_ in a non-contrived sentence.

Comment: You have outdone yourself, my dear. The reason that "until he had been fifteen" is unnecessary here is that one becomes some age, once, and at a fixed point in time in this case.

Comment: @Lambie I also provided examples where the simple past does not need to change in reported speech because I would not want the OP to think  the exception lies only with the age of someone. There are other exceptions.

Comment: Yes, Mari-Lou, when something occurs at a fixed point in time. A one-off event. William said that he had bought clothes in London when he went there. Right? He went there three times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 'until he had been fifteen' string.

1. There's nothing wrong with the 'had been fifteen' string in certain sentences:

- *He had been fifteen when he had first noticed that people were gradually leaving the village.* [though past simple is usually chosen where no loss of clarity occurs]

2. There's nothing wrong with the 'until he had been' etc string:

- *He had had no fear of animals until he had been bitten by a dog.*
- *They were quarantined until they had been checked for Covid.*

But notice that 'had been bitten' and 'had been checked' are punctive (happening in an instant, or near enough) rather than stative. This is not true with 'until he had been fifteen'. 'Until X had been' requires a punctive verb, not word/s expressing a state..

- **The Blue Morpho had been remarkably ugly until it had been an imago.* [the adult butterfly form]
- *The Blue Morpho had been remarkably ugly until it had become an imago.*
- *The Blue Morpho had been remarkably ugly until it had metamorphosed.*
- ??/**William said that he had lived in China until he had been fifteen.*
- *William said that he had lived in China until he had reached the age of fifteen.*

Comment: The core problem for the OP is that "*For example, the past simple will be changed to the past perfect simple*" Which I addressed clearly in my answer.

Comment: “*And others have clearly addressed in previous ones. The issue which remains an ELU topic (unless I've missed duplicates here) is the acceptability of 'until he had been fifteen' anywhere in a non-contrived sentence.*" What would the examples cited in your answer be if they were transposed into direct speech? I don't see a single example in your answer. The dilemma, which was expressed clearly by the OP, is transforming direct speech into reported speech.

Comment: 'William said that he had lived in China until he was fifteen.' is fine, ELL standard? Certainly duplicate. Backshifting unnecessary, which gets round the core problem. 'William said that he had lived in China until he had turned / reached the age of fifteen' are fine, with the optional backshifting licensed by the punctive (inchoative here) verbs. 'William said that he had lived in China until he had been fifteen' is not available, as detailed above.